# How to insert editable dropdown in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I know how to add dropdown in Laravel, but what about editable dropdown?

```
{{ Form::select('unit', $units, Input::old('unit'), ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```

Comment: How do you do that in simple HTML?

Comment: @EddyTheDove Is there something like Laravel-way?

Comment: I want to know how do that in pure html with a single input.

Comment: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=form_widget_editable_select

Comment: I see... you jsut need to pass `selectBoxOptions` to your input.

Comment: You got it working?

Comment: In order to use the `Form` facade you should make sure first that you have pulled in the `laravel/collective' package.

Check: https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#drop-down-lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I achieved like this(I am using Laravel 4 now, if you use 5, you should change {{ }} to {!! !!}).

```
var availableNames = {{ json_encode($itemnames) }};

$("input#name").autocomplete({
    source: availableNames,
    minLength: 0,
    delay: 0
}).focus(function () {
    //reset result list's pageindex when focus on
    $(this).autocomplete("search");
});
```